# How do I recursively traverse and log the properties of a HttpRequestMessage in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api, expandoobject

Thanks for looking!

## Background

I am working on an MVC4 .NET application and have written a filter to catch all errors (application-wide), log said errors, and then report them to the dev team via an HTML-formatted email.

The filter I have written pick up the HttpActionExecutedContext and from there I can derive the exception, stack trace, method called, and a bunch of other useful info.

Most of the info I access is in the form of a string or IDictionary and I use a helper method to iterate these items and put them into an HTML table for the report e-mail.

There is one property, however, that is giving me grief: the HttpRequestMessage property.

This property of the HttpActionExecutedContext object (HttpActionExecutedContext.Request.Properties) has many nested properties of different types.

## Problem

I am running into several road blocks to traversing this HttpActionExecutedContext.Request.Properties object in a recursive manner and resolving it to a hierarchy of KV pairs.  The problems are due to null values, type mismatches, and so on.

Here is the current result that I am getting from the Request.Properties:

> MS_HttpContext:
>   System.Web.HttpContextWrapper
>
> MS_RetrieveClientCertificateDelegate: System.Func`2[System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage,System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]
>
> MS_IsLocal:
>   Value is not created.
>
> MS_IncludeErrorDetail:
>   Value is not created.
>   MS_HttpRouteData: 
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HostedHttpRouteData
>
> MS_SynchronizationContext:
>   System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext
>
> MS_HttpConfiguration: 
>   System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration
>
> MS_DependencyScope:
>   System.Web.Http.Dependencies.EmptyResolver
>
> MS_DisposableRequestResources:    >System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.IDisposable]

So you can see that all I am really getting back in terms of a value is the `type` for the property.  I need the `value`.  If that value is a nested dictionary or something, that's fine, but I need to traverse it and log it's KV pairs because just giving me the type of the object is not useful.

## Question

How do I traverse this object recursively and end up with a dictionary of KV pairs (with some of the values being a dictionary themselves)?  Is there a helper class or some sort of dynamic method I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use something like JSON.NET and let it convert the object to json. You can then work with that json data and set some nesting limit or you can log the whole json string itself.